# iOS static table in a view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5

Sorry if this is a really silly question but I'm new to iOS. I'm trying to do this:

[image]

The table cells are static as the content shouldn't change (the options are the same all the time). I also need to place the submit and cancel buttons below and replace the red background with an image.

My problem is, I get the error saying:

> static table views are only valid when embedded in uitableviewcontroller

So my question is, how would I embed a table inside my view, like any other element?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: You can use TableViewController instead

Comment: But how would I then place other elements around it (e.g the buttons)?

Comment: Are you using IB to build that screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two relatively simple options to build a screen like that:

1. Make your controller a `UITableViewController, add two sections to the bottom of your static part, and put [custom cells with buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1244332/335858) into these two sections, or
2. Define the static content of your table in code.

The look of your screen will change slightly for option 1, but it is important only when you have many cells, forcing the sections with buttons off the screen until the user scrolls.

The second option requires writing some code, but not too much to cause you too much inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :) For the second option, would that mean that I can just embed the table view into my UIViewController and keep it dynamic?

Comment: @DavidOmid Yes, your table would be "dynamic", but the data behind it will be initialized statically, for example, in an `NSArray`.